# Ant automation from windows machine to linux

Tags: linux, windows, shell, docker, ant

I am running ant script on my Windows machine. From Windows I login in to a Linux server and run few basic commands.

Is there a way to make this automated using ant script or any scripting methods?

Comment: Have you tried looking into Ant's `sshexec` and `sshsession` tasks?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

In the example below i install application that the installer is Multiplatform and created on Windows machine and i run the commands on Linux machine (after copied to the linux machine) .

I suggest that you will use plink.exe, pscp.exe.

echo '***Coping installation files***'
%Jenkins_tools%\pscp.exe -pw  "%Install_path%\%installation%*unix*%newversion%.sh" root@%server_ip%:/opt/

%Jenkins_tools%\pscp.exe -pw  "C:\Jenkins\deployment\responsefiles\%installation%\response.varfile" root@%server_ip%:/opt/

echo '*** Running Installation** '
%Jenkins_tools%\plink.exe -ssh root@%server_ip% -P 22 -pw  chmod +x /opt/%installation%

%Jenkins_tools%\plink.exe -ssh root@%server_ip% -P 22 -pw  /opt/%installation%*.sh -varfile /opt/response.varfile -q